# Convert two-dimensional correlation matrix to javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary

I have a correlation table formatted as a two-dimensional array:

```
[
    [ 'xxx', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
    [ 'abc',   '1', '0.5', '0.7'],
    [ 'def', '0.5',   '1', '0.9'],
    [ 'ghi', '0.7', '0.9',   '1'],
]
```

I need to return it as a javascript object:

```
{ 
    'abc': {
        'abc': 1,
        'def': 0.5,
        'ghi': 0.7
    },
    'def': {
        'abc': 0.5,
        'def': 1,
        'ghi': 0.9
    },
    'ghi': {
        'abc': 0.7,
        'def': 0.9,
        'ghi': 1
    }
}
```

The rows / columns are not sorted.

Looking for a function to parse the array (approx 500x500 in size).

Comment: what have you tried? It appears you have made no attempt. You should do some research, try some code, and come back here if you have any specific question. Hint: read about `Array.reduce`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a nested iteration and assign the values only for indices who are not zero.

```js
const
    data = [['xxx', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['abc', '1', '0.5', '0.7'], ['def', '0.5', '1', '0.9'], ['ghi', '0.7', '0.9', '1']],
    result = data.reduce((r, w, i, a) => {
        if (i) w.forEach((v, j, b) => {
            if (j) (r[b[0]] ??= {})[a[0][j]] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reduce the data entries; and within each entry, reduce the fields.

```js
const matrixToObjectArray = (data) => {
  const [[, ...fields], ...entries] = data;
  return entries.reduce((acc, [ key, ...values ]) =>
    ({...acc, [key]: fields.reduce((record, field, index) =>
      ({ ...record, [field]: +values[index] }), {})}), {});
};

const data = [
  [ 'xxx' , 'abc' , 'def' , 'ghi' ],
  [ 'abc' ,   '1' , '0.5' , '0.7' ],
  [ 'def' , '0.5' ,   '1' , '0.9' ],
  [ 'ghi' , '0.7' , '0.9' ,   '1' ],
];

const expected = { 
  'abc': { 'abc': 1   , 'def': 0.5 , 'ghi': 0.7 },
  'def': { 'abc': 0.5 , 'def': 1   , 'ghi': 0.9 },
  'ghi': { 'abc': 0.7 , 'def': 0.9 , 'ghi': 1   }
};

const actual = matrixToObjectArray(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected));
console.log(actual);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You can turn this into a one-liner by utilizing an IIFE:

```js
const matrixToObjectArray = (data) =>
  (([[, ...fields], ...entries]) =>
    entries.reduce((acc, [ key, ...values ]) =>
    ({...acc, [key]: fields.reduce((record, field, index) =>
      ({ ...record, [field]: +values[index] }), {})}), {}))
  (data);
```

Code golf fun (110 bytes):

```js
// Where f = matrixToObjectArray
f=(d)=>(([[,...g],...e])=>e.reduce((m,[k,...w])=>({...m,[k]:g.reduce((r,f,i)=>({...r,[f]:+w[i]}),{})}),{}))(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first compute the header object from the first row as a lookup for fetching the values later on.

Then from the 2nd row you can iterate and use the header object built above to retrieve the values at proper indices.

```js
const correlationMatrix = [
  ['xxx', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
  ['abc', '1', '0.5', '0.7'],
  ['def', '0.5', '1', '0.9'],
  ['ghi', '0.7', '0.9', '1'],
];

const toJavascriptObject = (correlationMatrix) => {
  const headerObj = correlationMatrix[0]
    .slice(1)
    .reduce((r, c, idx) => {
      r[idx] = c;
      return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

  return correlationMatrix
    .slice(1)
    .map((c) => {

      const obj = c
        .slice(1)
        .reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
          acc[headerObj[idx]] = curr;
          return acc;
        }, Object.create(null));

      return {
        [c[0]]: obj
      };
    });
};

console.log(toJavascriptObject(correlationMatrix));
```

Answer (score 0):

read about `Array.reduce()` and `Array.slice(1)` and then try

```
function arrayToColumnar(arr) {
  let cols = arr[0].slice(1);
  return arr.slice(1).reduce( (res,row) => {  // for each row
    res[row[0]] = // use the row name as field name
      row.slice(1).reduce( (a,e,i) => {  // then for each column 
        a[cols[i]] = e;  // use the column name as field name
        return a;  // return the row transformed into object
    },{}) 
    return res;  // return all rows transformed into object 
  },{})
}
```